# PHP grpc extension not working on WAMP, despite working on CLI

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore, wamp, extension-methods

After about a week of trying to install grpc for Firestore with PHP, I managed to get it working, however only when ran in terminals / cmd. This php.ini / environment is on my desktop in a folder and when executing files with firestore commands it works. No errors.

However, when in WAMP, it crashes the page with:

```
      Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException: The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions. in D:\wamp64\www\karma\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\ClientTrait.php:76 Stack trace: #0 D:\wamp64\www\karma\vendor\google\cloud-firestore\src\FirestoreClient.php(139): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->requireGrpc() #1 D:\wamp64\www\karma\functions.php(32): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->__construct(Array) #2 D:\wamp64\www\karma\Firestore.php(8): Firestore->__construct('test') #3 {main} thrown in D:\wamp64\www\karma\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\ClientTrait.php on line 76
```

Now what is really weird is that I copied the directory from desktop and literally pasted it into the WAMP PHP area and there is no difference. It even says in the config that php_grpc is loaded! I dont think the bottom dlls are needed so I don't think its an issue they're missing but I find it incredibly strange **the same directory on the desktop will run php files from the command line but not in WAMP.** WAMP is 64 bit and so is the plugin. PHP version of wamp was 7.0.1 but I replaced the whole 7.0.1 folder with the new 7.4.x version as with the plugin of that version.

[image: grpc active]

Why would it say its loaded and yet say it isnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to completely reinstall wamp to fix this error, in a new directory, reinstall php and made sure I had the correct grpc version. I have no idea what caused the error, but try every recent grpc version (I think there is four) and ensure that in your config file every addition copies the format.

I had a new php install outside of WAMP which worked, but as wamp has it's own that was bugged for me

Answer (score 0):

I too have have the same issue.I tried all possible ways to fix it.The extension is loaded in waamp but the php shows missing error.

Comment: I will post my answer on here, check it out. It took me about 10 days to figure it out.